# Insert value into jk-rating-stars element using angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, angularjs-controller

Hello I would like to know how to put a value into rating="ctrl.rating" with $scope angular js.

```js
<jk-rating-stars max-rating="5" rating="ctrl.rating"
    read-only="ctrl.readOnly" on-rating="ctrl.onRating(rating)">
</jk-rating-stars>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl as ctrl">
    <jk-rating-stars max-rating="5" rating="ctrl.rating"
        read-only="ctrl.readOnly" on-rating="ctrl.onRating(rating)">
    </jk-rating-stars>
</div>
```

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial', 'jkAngularRatingStars'])

.controller('MyCtrl', function() {
    this.rating = 3;
    this.readOnly = false;
    this.onRating = function(rating){
      alert('On Rating: ' + rating);
    };
});
```

## [The DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/G3Y6YVMXQMoeFfjZc42j?p=preview)

```js
angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial', 'jkAngularRatingStars'])

.controller('MyCtrl', function() {
    this.rating = 3;
    this.readOnly = false;
    this.onRating = function(rating){
      console.log('On Rating: ' + rating);
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular-aria/angular-aria.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/angular-material/angular-material.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/angular-material/angular-material.css" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/angular-jk-rating-stars/dist/jk-rating-stars.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/angular-jk-rating-stars/dist/jk-rating-stars.js"></script>

  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl as ctrl">
    <jk-rating-stars max-rating="5" rating="ctrl.rating"
        read-only="ctrl.readOnly" on-rating="ctrl.onRating(rating)">
    </jk-rating-stars>
    <br>
    <input type="number" ng-model="ctrl.rating" />
  </body>
```